# foreground color not getting applied first time in radio button in windows phone 7, if radio button is disabled

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1

Foreground color not getting applied first time in radio button in windows phone 7, if radio button is disabled.

Here is my code-

```
RadioButton1.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 100, 0));//Green
RadioButton2.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255));//White
RadioButton3.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255));
RadioButton4.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255));

RadioButton1.IsEnabled = false;
RadioButton1.IsChecked = true;
RadioButton2.IsEnabled = false;
RadioButton3.IsEnabled = false;
RadioButton4.IsEnabled = false;
```

here is my xaml

```
                <StackPanel x:Name="panel" Orientation="Vertical" >
                    <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton1">
                        <RadioButton.Content>
                            <TextBlock Text="" x:Name="RadioButton1Text" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        </RadioButton.Content>
                    </RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton2">
                        <RadioButton.Content>
                            <TextBlock Text="" x:Name="RadioButton2Text" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        </RadioButton.Content>
                    </RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton3">
                        <RadioButton.Content>
                            <TextBlock Text="" x:Name="RadioButton3Text" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        </RadioButton.Content>
                    </RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton4">
                        <RadioButton.Content>
                            <TextBlock Text="" x:Name="RadioButton4Text" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        </RadioButton.Content>
                    </RadioButton>
                </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

The template for the `RadioButton` has a different visual state for when it is disabled. The changes made when it transitions between the disabled state will update the `Foreground` property and so overwrite the explicit change you are making in code.

Depending on exactly what you are trying to achieve you could create a new style for the radiobutton which alters the template changes for the disabled state or you could indicate whatever you're trying to indicate by altering the ForegroundBrush in a different way.

Comment: Hi Matt, i understood the concept you are saying but don't know how to achieve that. I have put xaml snapshot.